# How are topological materials considered "protected by the gap" if the electrons couple to gapless phonons?

Tags: topological-insulators, phonons

My understanding is that Hamiltonians are usually classified topologically by whether they can be continuously transformed into each other without closing the band gap.

I then usually hear claims about the robustness of the topological character against sufficiently weak (symmetry-preserving) perturbations.

However: this gap, from my admittedly limited experience, is often calculated for one specific kind of quasiparticle at a time (in the cases I've most looked at, electrons).

So how does this "robustness" apply if we couple to a gapless mode (say, phonons)? Are electronic bandstructure TIs not robust against coupling to phonons? Are the kinds of couplings to phonons not "the right type" to break the topology for some reason?

Comment: this might be of interest to you: https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6395

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, the gap is part of the Hamilonian; it is calculated for one particle as the Hamiltonian is the Hamiltonian of this particle. The phonon-electron Hamiltonian could look differently and could have different eigenstates (as Cooper pairs), but most phonon-electron interactions are shortlived.

Phonons can facilitate transition between the electronic eigenstates (and do so e.g. together with photons in indirect semiconductors), but those transitions are not part of the electronic Hamiltonian but of the phonon-electron Hamiltonian and are not eigenstates in the sense that cooper pairs or electronic bands are eigenstates.

I understand your question as "why do we not consider this for topological insulators" and not as the question for new kinds of topological insulators, for which someone else should answer.
Please comment if this answer needs improvement.

Comment: I guess what I'm really asking about is how far topological robustness goes. It makes sense that the single-particle band gap protects against single-particle Hamiltonian perturbations, or a (hypothetical) multi-particle gap against interacting perturbations. But not that a single-particle gap can protect against all sufficiently weak perturbations (including interacting perturbations). And if the gaps we actually compute are vulnerable to these other kinds of perturbations, then how "robust" is our robustness really?

Comment: The system I was looking at was one akin to TBG, where an interacting instability breaks a degeneracy of flat bands via Chern ferromagnetism. There, I was wondering how robust the topological this interacting gap was if we couple it to gapless modes. I'm not sure if that's a "new kind" of TI or an old kind of TI, by the classification you refer to.